# Ubuntu Server is randomly going down

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I am having some trouble with my Digital Ocean's server which has a blog running on Wordpress.
Randomly the server goes on 100% memory/processing and over 200MB/s Disk IO until the blog crashes.

If I restart apache the server comes back to normal.
This is happening over three times a week and it has nothing to do with many users using the site at the same time.

I have browsed the internet and used some solutions and nothing has really helped. 
I am using the following:

```
- Wordpress version: 4.7.2

- Php version:
PHP 5.6.28-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

- Linux Version:
Linux 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 16.04 server
```

I've spent some time looking on logfiles and the dmesg, fail2ban, faillog, and syslog does not have anything unusual.

However the apache error.log and access.log has some interesting things.

On the error log I've seen a lot of lines like these ones:

```
[Wed Oct 25 16:43:31.234364 2017] [:error] [pid 23211] [client 172.68.26.39:37081] PHP Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=23211 in public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877, referer: https://sitename/blogpostname/comment-page-6/
[Wed Oct 25 16:43:31.615950 2017] [:error] [pid 23216] [client 172.68.27.196:15015] PHP Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=23216 in public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877, referer: https://www.google.com.br/
[Wed Oct 25 16:43:31.600365 2017] [:error] [pid 23224] [client 172.68.27.64:20351] PHP Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=23224 in public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877, referer: https://www.google.com.br/
[Wed Oct 25 16:43:32.736840 2017] [:error] [pid 22410] [client 162.158.74.163:17321] PHP Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=22410 in public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877
```

Went on the wp-db.php file on line 1877 and it is a random usual line on the file, nothing wrong with it.

After a google search I've seen a lot of people with the same problem changing some variables on the php and apache configuration files. 
So I've increased the following variables:

```
max_execution_time
max_allowed_packet_size
max_user_connections
max_connections 
And disabled the W3 Total Cache plugin
```

Still with no Luck.
Checked the cronjobs and it doesn't have any job which trigger at the same time that I had this problem.

I am putting the apache's error.log and access.log and mysql error.log on the above links, in case you need them. 
Last time I had this issue was 25 OCT 16:40h until the restart of the apache service at 16:57h

Some lines on the MYSQL ERROR LOG FILE

```
            2017-10-25T18:40:00.355353Z 11952 [Note] Aborted connection 11952 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:40:01.869160Z 12116 [Note] Aborted connection 12116 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:43:10.465788Z 12185 [Note] Aborted connection 12185 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:43:11.058421Z 12199 [Note] Aborted connection 12199 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:43:13.415412Z 12187 [Note] Aborted connection 12187 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:43:15.844868Z 12186 [Note] Aborted connection 12186 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:43:21.387382Z 12217 [Note] Aborted connection 12217 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:43:21.418078Z 12218 [Note] Aborted connection 12218 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:43:21.747628Z 12093 [Note] Aborted connection 12093 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:43:24.705706Z 12219 [Note] Aborted connection 12219 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.267584Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.268753Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.812542Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.874865Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 23296 ...
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.945767Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.945855Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.945891Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.945902Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.945911Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.945922Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.954531Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.957647Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
            2017-10-25T18:43:29.962895Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
            2017-10-25T18:43:30.069723Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
            2017-10-25T18:44:29.139834Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate 1677722136 bytes of memory after 60 retries over 60 seconds. OS error: Cannot allocate memory (12). Check if you should increase the swap file or ulimits of your operating system. Note that on most 32-bit computers the process memory space is limited to 2 GB or 4 GB.
            2017-10-25 16:44:29 0x7fec07b49740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140651718285120 in file ut0ut.cc line 931
            InnoDB: Failing assertion: !m_fatal
            InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
            InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
            InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
            InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
            InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
            InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
            InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
            18:44:29 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
            This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
            or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
            or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
            Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
            As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
            collection process might fail.

            key_buffer_size=16777216
            read_buffer_size=131072
            max_used_connections=0
            max_threads=151
            thread_count=0
            connection_count=0
            It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
            key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 76382 K  bytes of memory
            Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

            Thread pointer: 0x0
            Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
            where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
            terribly wrong...
            stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
            /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xe7f80b]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x489)[0x784769]
            /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x113d0)[0x7fec06ac03d0]
            /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7fec05e7a418]
            /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7fec05e7c01a]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x75a5ee]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN2ib14fatal_or_errorD2Ev+0x2e8)[0x1116f58]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xfd53c5]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z8log_initv+0x4a5)[0xfdba25]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x22ed)[0x10bcd3d]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xf81339]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x51)[0x7d1bc1]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xc665b5]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x608)[0xc6dc58]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x77cce4]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x7e4)[0x77e264]
            /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fec05e65830]
            /usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x29)[0x774c79]
            The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
            information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
            2017-10-25T18:44:29.747705Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
            2017-10-25T18:44:29.747973Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.168154Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.175188Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 23379 ...
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.227947Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.228037Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.228056Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.228067Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.228075Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.228083Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.229957Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.231671Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.235573Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
            2017-10-25T18:44:30.262313Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
            2017-10-25T18:45:26.314564Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
            2017-10-25T18:45:26.351139Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
            2017-10-25T18:45:26.387449Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 162362845023
            2017-10-25T18:45:26.387528Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 162362845032
            2017-10-25T18:45:26.387864Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 162362845032
            2017-10-25T18:45:26.387888Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
            2017-10-25T18:45:26.387932Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
            2017-10-25T18:45:27.653149Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
            2017-10-25T18:45:27.655693Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
            2017-10-25T18:45:27.655993Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
            2017-10-25T18:45:27.832424Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
            2017-10-25T18:45:27.839253Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
            2017-10-25T18:45:27.839314Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
            2017-10-25T18:45:27.841792Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
            2017-10-25T18:45:27.897127Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.15 started; log sequence number 162362845032
            2017-10-25T18:45:27.913296Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
            2017-10-25T18:45:27.921641Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
            2017-10-25T18:45:28.017907Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
            2017-10-25T18:45:28.018041Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
            2017-10-25T18:45:28.018712Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
            2017-10-25T18:45:28.019306Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
            2017-10-25T18:45:28.163336Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
            2017-10-25T18:45:28.166514Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
            Version: '5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
            2017-10-25T18:45:30.429764Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171025 16:45:30
            2017-10-25T18:53:52.366879Z 159 [Note] Aborted connection 159 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:03.345944Z 200 [Note] Aborted connection 200 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:04.660063Z 199 [Note] Aborted connection 199 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:05.729653Z 177 [Note] Aborted connection 177 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:12.520890Z 205 [Note] Aborted connection 205 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:12.669290Z 155 [Note] Aborted connection 155 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:16.064185Z 175 [Note] Aborted connection 175 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:19.823038Z 51 [Note] Aborted connection 51 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:20.741167Z 206 [Note] Aborted connection 206 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:20.746381Z 42 [Note] Aborted connection 42 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:24.312023Z 122 [Note] Aborted connection 122 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:24.352842Z 186 [Note] Aborted connection 186 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:25.449125Z 148 [Note] Aborted connection 148 to db: '<Database name>' user: '<Database User>' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
            2017-10-25T18:56:28.626509Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
            2017-10-25T18:56:28.626841Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.071894Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.105638Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 23873 ...
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.235898Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.236056Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.236126Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.236150Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.236167Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.236182Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.239770Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.243200Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.297785Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
            2017-10-25T18:56:30.471494Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
            2017-10-25T18:57:24.662239Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
            2017-10-25T18:57:24.855967Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
            2017-10-25T18:57:24.892537Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 162362990185
            2017-10-25T18:57:24.892649Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 162362990194
            2017-10-25T18:57:24.893393Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 162362990194
            2017-10-25T18:57:24.893430Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
            2017-10-25T18:57:24.893449Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.486004Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.486109Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.486191Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.561775Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.565595Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.565662Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.583476Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.15 started; log sequence number 162362990194
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.585667Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.589295Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.661688Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.661775Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.661845Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.661935Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.756913Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.758546Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
            Version: '5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
            2017-10-25T18:57:25.958884Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171025 16:57:25
```

Some lines of the Apache Error.log

```
                [Wed Oct 25 06:25:48.823233 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17104] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
                [Wed Oct 25 16:40:06.602720 2017] [:error] [pid 22585] [client 172.68.25.164:33251] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=22585 in /var/www/<site name>/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877, referer: https://<site name>/2015/05/27/o-gerente-responde-qual-a-melhor-opcao-para-amortizar-o-financiamento-imobiliario/
                [Wed Oct 25 16:40:35.820625 2017] [:error] [pid 22700] [client 162.158.74.163:29857] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=22700 in /var/www/<site name>/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877, referer: https://<site name>/amortizacao-prazo-ou-parcela/
                [Wed Oct 25 16:41:30.171910 2017] [:error] [pid 22751] [client 172.68.254.178:19539] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=22751 in /var/www/<site name>/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877
                [Wed Oct 25 16:44:52.784567 2017] [:error] [pid 22463] [client 108.162.219.224:10437] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=22463 in /var/www/mkt.<site name>/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 1176
                [Wed Oct 25 16:44:53.006562 2017] [:error] [pid 22892] [client 172.68.26.63:12817] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=22892 in /var/www/<site name>/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877, referer: http://www.google.com.br/
                [Wed Oct 25 16:44:56.689245 2017] [:error] [pid 22862] [client 108.162.219.224:9729] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=22862 in /var/www/mkt.<site name>/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 1176
                [Wed Oct 25 16:45:25.240149 2017] [:error] [pid 23208] [client 172.68.25.68:29319] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=23208 in /var/www/<site name>/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877, referer: https://<site name>/2015/04/08/maquinas-de-cartao-de-credito-um-comparativo/
                [Wed Oct 25 16:45:25.336803 2017] [:error] [pid 23228] [client 172.68.25.68:24895] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=23228 in /var/www/<site name>/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877, referer: https://<site name>/2015/04/08/maquinas-de-cartao-de-credito-um-comparativo/
                [Wed Oct 25 16:45:47.340049 2017] [:error] [pid 22925] [client 172.68.25.26:15907] PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=22925 in /var/www/<site name>/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877
AH00045: child process 22899 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
                [Wed Oct 25 16:57:24.320984 2017] [core:warn] [pid 17104] AH00045: child process 22911 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
                [Wed Oct 25 16:57:24.321014 2017] [core:warn] [pid 17104] AH00045: child process 22923 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
                [Wed Oct 25 16:57:25.323354 2017] [core:warn] [pid 17104] AH00045: child process 23840 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
                [Wed Oct 25 16:57:25.323570 2017] [core:warn] [pid 17104] AH00045: child process 23899 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
                [Wed Oct 25 16:57:25.323586 2017] [core:warn] [pid 17104] AH00045: child process 22649 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
                [Wed Oct 25 16:57:26.325315 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17104] 
    AH00051: child pid 23899 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`
                    [Wed Oct 25 16:57:29.895519 2017] [core:notice] [pid 24045] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
                    [Wed Oct 25 16:57:27.326904 2017] [core:error] [pid 17104] AH00046: child process 23840 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
                    [Wed Oct 25 16:57:27.329833 2017] [core:error] [pid 17104] AH00046: child process 22649 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
                    [Wed Oct 25 16:57:28.340357 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17104] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
                    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/newrelic.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/newrelic.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
                    [Wed Oct 25 16:57:29.894473 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24045] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2g-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
```

My configuration files:

mysqld.cnf

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
```

my.cnf

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
#innodb_log_file_size = 256M
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
#innodb_file_format = Barracuda
max_allowed_packet = 1G
innodb_log_file_size = 500M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 800M
innodb_strict_mode = 0
wait_timeout = 100
```

php.ini

```
[PHP]

engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
asp_tags = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 17
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = On
max_execution_time = 100
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = -1
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 24M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60

[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On

[Date]

[filter]

[iconv]

[intl]

[sqlite3]

[Pcre]

[Pdo]

[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

[Phar]

[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.cache_size = 2000
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off

[OCI8]]

[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10

[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0

[browscap]

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatibility_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off

[Assertion]

[COM]

[mbstring]

[gd]

[exif]

[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
```

The GLOBAL STATUS and GLOBAL VARIABLES are on dropbox files:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzquqp4jfrs6z43/SHOW%20GLOBAL%20STATUS.txt?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5p0hwlq2ma3c6jd/SHOW%20GLOBAL%20VARIABLES.txt?dl=0

And the Engine InnoDb status

```
Type    Name    Status
InnoDB      "=====================================
                2017-10-27 ..."
```

Comment: Might be an endless loop somewhere. Maybe log each request's start and finish with timestamp and you'll be able to find those that never finish (and therefore never get written to the access log)?

Comment: According to your posted error log in the 25th line, something had just asked for  1677722136    bytes of RAM.  That is a Gig and a half.  
Then assertion error is documented in the log.  We need to know how much RAM your MySQL server has and please post in your Question text results of 

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS:

Comment: Post your MySQL complete cfg.ini and php.ini as well, please.

Comment: I've inserted the configuration files.
Everything that is not there is commented.
The  SHOW GLOBAL STATS is too long for me to put here, so i've put on the dropbox links to the files.

Comment: Thanks, how much RAM does your server have?  CPU's?  HDD or SSD storage and number of GB each?

Comment: My server is a dual core with 2GB of ram qith 40GB SSD disk size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following suggestions need your research before implementing ONLY one item per day.  Some may be applied dynamically.  Suggested cfg/ini values follow, could be modify, add or remove.

```
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=1 # from OFF to record in error log for CORRECTION
slow_query_log=1 # from OFF to record for possible CORRECTION
innodb_log_buffer_size=838860800  REMOVE to allow default of 16M (buffer size is larger than file size today and likely your most significant difficulty) NOT a dynamic variable
thread_cache_size=100 #from 8 to support 500 created threads since start
innodb_read_ahead_threshold=8 #from 56 for your intensity of reading
innodb_stats_sample_pages=32 #from 8 for more accurate cardinality of ndx's
have_query_cache=NO #from yes default since you have no intention of using qc
query_cache_size=0 #from 16M to conserve RAM
key_buffer_size=1M #from 16M, only used by ISAM.  Low requirements
key_cache_age_threshold=64800 #from 300 seconds, avoid RD for 8 hours
max_write_lock_count=128 #from enormous number to allow RD after this nn
sql_select_limit=1000000000 #from enormous number to 1 Billion rows selected limit
table_open_cache= 10000 #from 2000 to support 40,000 opened since start.
```

ulimit needs to be reviewed and made more tolerant, if possible.
When appropriate, provide feedback, please.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
since this problem occurency is random, I've put the two first lines there, and will see if the log files can show me more information

Comment: The third line will likely correct the 'random' problem.  The others will only make the system more responsive to user requests.  Change only one a day.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I'm changing this variable right now.
I think this might be the problem. The 'random' problem occured again and after googling some stuff on the new logfiles, I've encoutered this page, which basically says that the buffer can't be larger than the file size. 
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80668

I will change this value and update with results. Thanks

Comment: For MySQL and most systems, if BUFFER SIZE > FILE SIZE = trouble because you would be 'exceeding' the next push of data to requested destination process.

Comment: So, I had changed some variables as you suggested, and i had the same error a couple of times again. So I decided to change all the variables as you suggested. Some of them crashed mysql on the restart procedure. these are: 
have_query_cache=0 
key_age_threshold=64800 
sql_sql_limit=1000000000 
Now I will likely wait a week or so to see if the problem happens again and reply with feedback.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Still no luck... The server crashed today again. Mysql error log says: [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 1048576)  and [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000). Which is confusing because my table_open_cache is set to 2000 on my.cnf. Not sure if I need to change max_open_files too.

Comment: Please post current results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%_size' to allow verification of all _sizes.  Please do this today.  Consider installing the software from mysqltuner.com and posting the test report.  We will then know your RAM, number of tables/size by ENGINE and could influence suggestions.  Some of the recmmendations of mysqltuner should be ignored.  Be careful, do your own research, please.  Please check ulimits and expand to support more activity.

Comment: Please post current content of my.cnf/ini and errorlog from crash 15 minutes ago.

Comment: error.log -  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ob7h7m8ge3pwpmv/error.log?dl=0 and the my.cnf -  https://www.dropbox.com/s/39zgxr1vtposejx/my.cnf?dl=0

Comment: @vmansur  Please review this link for information on increasing number of open files In Linux  https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/    Please consider getting your Hard ulimit to 100000 and the Soft limit to 60000.  Then in your my.cnf A. net_read_timeout=45 # from 30 to avoid 'Aborted connection' and B. open_files_limit=30000 # from 1048576 and C. table_open_cache=10000 # to support 40,000 opened tables in 2 working days (this line is disabled at this time, pull off the leading #  and  D. max_allowed_packet=1G is likely causing OOM.  Lower it to your minimum reqd.

Comment: @vmansur your drop box status of a few weeks ago has these facts.  Bytes_received 835M, Connections 37057, indicating one connection averaged sending 22,500 bytes to your host.  max_allowed_packet=1M should be fine for nearly all connections.  If you have a 'known', expected higher requirement, early in the 'session', you may SET @max_allowed_packet=1024*1024*1024; for 1G for this session, rather than all connections exposing you to OOM crash.  When the session is done, next connect will have 1M limit, as in my.cnf request.

Comment: Also, please post HTOP (preferred) or TOP text output into your question.  We NEED to know how much RAM your host has available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So i changed the variables as you described.
Htop usually shows that the system is using between 800MB and 900MB of memory. There is a screenshot. https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp1fa6bc6pbaqna/Captura%20de%20tela%20em%202017-11-17%2011-10-27.png?dl=0

Comment: Changed the max_allowed_packet to 128M, think it will be enough. 1024*1024*1024 for some reason didn't worked. It crashed mysqld

Comment: htop indicates you have a 2G machine.  When you try to run 1G just for max_allowed_packet, guess what, there is NOT enough RAM to support the request and BAM, Crash.

Comment: yes, so now i've changed to 128MB of max_packet_size. Do you think it is okay? Or should I just define as the default 16MB?

Comment: Leave it until further changes are necessary.

Comment: I think the problem has been solved.
I've changed the variables as you described, and additionally I've used the Percona wizard to tune up better mysql variables based on the server size. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you have made significant progress.  Your positive feedback is appreciated.  Happy Holidays.